# Can I ask whether a specific game/program is right for me?

Tags: discussion

I know you can ask for recommendations based on the criteria you give, but can I ask whether a game/program I've found will be right for me based on what I want from it?  For instance, "I found this program, I didn't like a program similar to it for these reasons, I like these things I've heard about the program."  Is that allowed on this site?

Answer (score 2):

Great question.  It's definitely a gray area.

My interest is to help as many people as possible, so therefore I would like to see every question on-topic.  But because of the current layout of StackExchange, this is not really possible.  Personally, I *often* wonder if SE would be better with only tags instead of many separate sites.  But I digress...

Instead of asking if a software package is "right for me", you could definitely write "these are my requirements, and I tried package XYZ and I didn't like it because of these reasons" (and then list the reasons).

Although I don't want to say it, I think asking "is software XYZ is a good fit for my requirements" (and then listing the requirements) will be considered off-topic by our community.

That said, what is considered on-topic and off-topic is ***not written in stone***.  Instead, it is defined by the desires of our community.  As an *elected* moderator, I'm very willing to go with whatever our community prefers.  Personally, I prefer your question to be considered sufficiently on-topic, but I think I'm likely in the minority.

Conclusion: You ask a great question. I think it's worth hearing what the rest of the community thinks.

P.S. Izzy has to buy us all a free drink when he posts that he thinks it's off-topic. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  What I may do is post my question and link this meta page if people want to discuss this.  I just hope users hold their downvotes until a consensus is reached.  =)